# ProgrammingError: column res_users.action_id does not exist

Tags: python, openerp-7

I used OpenERP from version version 7 n debian 7. The database is successfully created, but when I try to login I get the following error:

```
Server Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 306, in dispatch_rpc
result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 632, in dispatch
res = fn(db, uid, *params)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: column res_users.action_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...partner_id",res_users."id",res_users."company_id",res_users....
```

I checked password - all ok, can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your database is not created correctly.

There are some reasons for it.

1. You are missing some of core module addons.
2. You changed something in core.
3. OpenERP DB sometimes just creates problems of its own, in this
   case creation was faulty (most likely scenario)

I suggest downloading new version, try to get some stable one (not latest) and try to create DB again. Check in console what is happening when creating one.